# Navigate Website with PHP

Tags: php, parsing, web-crawler, mechanize, navigateurl

How can I navigate on a website, using php ? (I want with a local program to access a website and parse html pages, fill forms, click buttons and being redirected, etc.; as if PHP was a real guy). Yet, I use Ruby Mechanise but it's not sufficient.

Thanks

Comment: You need a Javascript-based automation or testing framework running in a real browser to do that; PHP isn't really able to interact with the site's javascript or do stuff real people do.

Answer (score 1):

To interact with a website you would most likely use a javascript framework such as **[phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/page-automation.html)** or **[dalekjs](http://dalekjs.com/)**. PHP is not made for DOM manipulation and interaction or page automation.

Comment: Can i use javascript locally (executed from my computer) to work on a distant website like google or SOF ?

Comment: this should work, allthought it is meant for local testing and they will most likely notice it and ask for capture really fast. just try some of the given examples.

Comment: Ok i will try. Was should I install to use js through mac os 10.10 ? Node.js ?

Comment: I'm trying with phantomjs and casperjs

Comment: I don't understand at all phantomjs and casperjs docs ...